# How to fix dead keys order fiasco?

Tags: keyboard, centos, centos-7

I have recently moved to CentOS as my operating system at work, and I have been facing a stupid, yet super annoying problem when typing.

I'm using an US keyboard in both its classic and international variants (so I can type accents in French for instance).

**Regardless of the active layout**, I found that having to type a pipe symbol (`|`), which is located on the same key as the `\` character, I have to proceed to the following key presses sequence:

<kbd>Shift (hold)</kbd>,<kbd>| (hold)</kbd>,<kbd>| (release)</kbd>,<kbd>Shift (release)</kbd>

Which produces the desired output: `|`

However, when typing fast, I often find myself releasing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> before the <kbd>|</kbd> key, like so:

<kbd>Shift (hold)</kbd>,<kbd>| (hold)</kbd>,<kbd>Shift (release)</kbd>,<kbd>| (release)</kbd>

This sadly, produces the following output: `|\`

I don't have this behavior on Ubuntu, or on Windows. It feels weird to me that release a control key (shift) causes a character output.

Is this a known bug ? Is there anything I could try to solve this ?